# Custom recursively columns view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to develop a custom recursively columns view. How to always select the first element of the next nested column in recursive way updating all descendant views?

Model

```swift
enum Sub: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case subItemA, subItemB, subItemC
}

enum Type: Hashable, Codable {
    case itemA(of: Sub?)
    case itemB(of: Sub?)
}

extension Type {
    func getName() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .itemA(of: .none): return "ITEM A"
        case .itemA(of: .subItemA): return "ITEM A - SUB A"
        
        case .itemB(of: .none): return "ITEM B"
        case .itemB(of: .subItemA): return "ITEM B - SUB A"
        case .itemB(of: .subItemB): return "ITEM B - SUB B"
        case .itemB(of: .subItemC): return "ITEM B - SUB C"
        default: return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}

struct Language: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String { return type.getName() }
    var type: Type
}

enum Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case let .item(item): return item.id
        case let .menu(lang, _): return lang.id
        case .divider: return ""
        }
    }
    case item(Language)
    indirect case menu(Language, items: [Item])
    case divider
}
```

Model view

```swift
final class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var menu: [Item]
    init() {
        menu = [.menu(Language(type: .itemA(of: .none)), items: [
                    .item(Language(type: .itemA(of: .subItemA))),
                ]),
                .divider,
                .menu(Language(type: .itemB(of: .none)), items: [
                    .item(Language(type: .itemB(of: .subItemA))),
                    .item(Language(type: .itemB(of: .subItemB))),
                    .item(Language(type: .itemB(of: .subItemC)))
                ])
        ]
    }
}
```

Recursive view

```swift
struct PrefView: View {
    @StateObject var menuVM = MenuViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NestedView(items: menuVM.menu)
    }
}

struct NestedView: View {
    let items: [Item]
    @State var selected: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { content in
                    switch content {
                    case .item(let lang), .menu(let lang, _):
                        Row(selection: $selected, lang: lang, item: content)
                    case .divider:
                        Divider()
                        .frame(width:300)
                    }
                }
            }
            if selected != nil {
                switch selected {
                case let .item(lang):
                    Text(lang.type.getName())
                case let .menu(_, items: subMenu):
                    NestedView(items: subMenu, selected: subMenu[0])  // <- Recursive
                case .divider:
                    Divider()
                case .none:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    @Binding var selection: Item?
    var lang: Language
    var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text(lang.type.getName())
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
        .background(item == selection ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
        .onTapGesture() {
            selection = item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, there is already a built in AppKit class for this: `NSBrowser`. You'll probably have an easier time by just wrapping it

Comment: thanks, but I’m looking for a swiftui oriented solution

Comment: Hence the "just so you know". SwiftUI isn't mature on macOS, and a lot of the native controls you're left to `Wrap` yourself, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've attached a reworking of the code that achieves what I hope is being asked about.

It was tested on macOS 12.1 with Xcode 13.2.1

The two main differences to the original code are:

1. The determination of the column data that the UI is to render is now done in a VM update method `setColumns`. Which is a bit more flexible and makes the View layout code easier to understand by removing the recursion.
2. There's now also a selected Item per Column (as opposed to for all Columns), as I think that's what was being intended. If it's not should be easy to change it in the `setColumns` method.

Fwiw: Previously spent a week or so experimenting with recursive tree rendering on macOS (the built-in on macOS renders a tree or draggable - but not both). If interested the tidied up version of the final experiment can be found [here](https://github.com/shufflingB/swiftui-macos-tree-list-demo).

Unfortunately the tree rendering experiment ended up as just a learning exercise as I came to much the same conclusion as [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) - bit too much needed implementing and bit too non-native for my app. Was fun project though, and other's have different requirements, so good luck :-)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var menuVM = MenuViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    ForEach($menuVM.columns) { column in
                        ColumnRender(
                            items: column.list.wrappedValue,
                            selected: column.selection
                        )
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .onChange(of: column.selection.wrappedValue) { newSelectedItem in
                            withAnimation {
                                menuVM.setColumns(newSelectedItem)
                            }
                        }
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
            Divider()
            DetailRender(item: menuVM.columns.last?.selection)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailRender: View {
    let item: Item?
    var body: some View {
        var lang: Language?
        if case let .item(l) = item {
            lang = l
        } else if case let .menu(l, _) = item {
            lang = l
        }
        let display: String = lang != nil ? lang!.type.getName() : "Nothing selected"

        return VStack {
            Text("\(display)")
        }
    }
}

struct ColumnRender: View {
    @State var items: [Item]
    @Binding var selected: Item?

    var body: some View {
        return List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            ItemRender(item: item, isSelected: selected == item)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selected = item
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemRender: View {
    let item: Item
    let isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        var lang: Language?
        if case let .item(l) = item {
            lang = l
        } else if case let .menu(l, _) = item {
            lang = l
        }

        return HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text(lang!.type.getName())
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
        .fixedSize()
        .background(isSelected ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
    }
}

struct Column: Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var list: Array<Item>
    var selection: Item?
}

final class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var menu: Array<Item>
    @Published var columns: Array<Column>

    init() {
        let demoData = Self.demoData()
        menu = demoData
        _columns = .init(wrappedValue: [Column(list: demoData, selection: nil)])
    }

    func setColumns(_ basedOnSelection: Item?) {
        guard let selection = basedOnSelection else {
            columns = [Column(list: Self.demoData(), selection: nil)]
            return
        }

        /// Find the index where the selection w
        let uSelectionInColIdx: Int? = columns.firstIndex(where: { $0.list.contains(selection) })

        guard let selectionInColIdx = uSelectionInColIdx else {
            print("Error - unable to find column idx for selected item, defaulting ")
            columns = [Column(list: Self.demoData(), selection: nil)]
            return
        }

        var tmpColumns: Array<Column> = Array(columns[0 ... selectionInColIdx])

        if case let .menu(_, items: subMenu) = selection {
            tmpColumns.append(Column(list: subMenu, selection: subMenu.first))
        }
        columns = tmpColumns
    }

    static func demoData() -> Array<Item> {
        /// NB: Adding the same "menu" as a child of *itself* will cause problems bc the algorithm that determines
        /// what columns to display when items are clicked on  will not know in which column the selected item was.
        return [
            .menu(Language(type: .itemA(of: .none)), items: [
                .item(Language(type: .itemA(of: .subItemA))),
            ]),
            .menu(Language(type: .itemB(of: .none)), items: [
                .item(Language(type: .itemB(of: .subItemA))),
                .item(Language(type: .itemB(of: .subItemB))),
                .item(Language(type: .itemB(of: .subItemC))),
                .menu(Language(type: .itemA(of: .none)), items: [
                    .item(Language(type: .itemA(of: .subItemA))),
                    .item(Language(type: .itemA(of: .subItemB))),
                ]),
            ]),
        ]
    }
}

enum Sub: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case subItemA, subItemB, subItemC
}

enum Type: Hashable, Codable {
    case itemA(of: Sub?)
    case itemB(of: Sub?)
}

extension Type {
    func getName() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .itemA(of: .none): return "ITEM A"
        case .itemA(of: .subItemA): return "ITEM A - SUB A"
        case .itemA(of: .subItemB): return "ITEM A - SUB B"

        case .itemB(of: .none): return "ITEM B"
        case .itemB(of: .subItemA): return "ITEM B - SUB A"
        case .itemB(of: .subItemB): return "ITEM B - SUB B"
        case .itemB(of: .subItemC): return "ITEM B - SUB C"
        default: return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}

struct Language: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String { return type.getName() }
    var type: Type
}

enum Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case let .item(item): return item.id
        case let .menu(lang, _): return lang.id
        }
    }

    case item(Language)
    indirect case menu(Language, items: [Item])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer! I also really enjoyed your tree rendering experiment on github: great job! I took some time to study your code. I need additional clarification. The most nested `.item` will obviously have to show something on the right (view / text). I've edited code and comments to yours for simplicity. In nested elements, the next `.menu` does not disappear if a `.item` is alternatively selected with relative detail. I added a short gif. Is it a bug?

Comment: In other words, to simulate recursion, the third column does not disappear if an element of type `.item` (In second column) is selected

Comment: Hi @Joannes,  I've slightly tweaked code in `setColumns` to fix handling of nesting as mentioned and added a stub for a detail view render. Couldn't resist adding a sprinking of animation to make it look nice  :-)

Comment: Thanks @shufflingb I really appreciated details of your explanation! `withAnimation` and `"Nothing selected"` are the icing on the cake! Thank you very much!